# DateTime Format Issue.Need output in HH:MM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

In one of my legacy applications,Following line of Code was there.Earlier objFrom1 after parsing containing HH:MM format,but now the same line of code after parsing returning H:MM format.Can you guys help me out that where is the problem?Its same lines of code from last few years,but suddenly output has changed due to which facing some issue

```
string From1 ="06:00 am";

DateTime objFrom1 = new DateTime();


objFrom1 = DateTime.Parse(From1);
```

**Now objFrom1 Contains Value 6:00 am**

Comment: A DateTime object doesn't have an inherent format, it just holds the data until you are ready to do something with it. You describe the format when you convert to a string etc such as `objFrom1.ToString("HH:mm")`.

Comment: @Belogix - "DateTime object doesn't have an inherent format" can't be stressed enough!

Comment: A sudden change after a long time may be due to the changes you have made in the System clock in control panel.. You might have changed the format of the date or time..

Comment: @Corak - Yes, I have seen this many times before where people see objects as strings (often due to the debugger etc). I have tried to expand on my comment a little in the answers to hopefully guide the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment. A `DateTime` object, like any object, **does NOT have an inherent format**, instead it just holds the data until you are ready to do something with it

What you are looking for is a string representation of that object. You therefore describe the format you are after when you convert to a string such as:

```
 string hourMinutes = objFrom1.ToString("HH:mm");
```

In addition you can do other formats such as:

```
 string dayMonthYearHourMinutes = objFrom1.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
```

You can also specify the format when doing other string operations such as:

```
string hourMinutes = string.Format("The time is: {0:HH:mm}", objFrom1);
```

Finally, you can Google or look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for more information about `DateTime` formats.

Answer (score 0):

```
string outputString = objFrom1.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Standard `DateTime` format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Building custom `DateTime` format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use String.Format to get apropriate output string for your DateTime value.

```
String.Format("{0:hh:mm tt}", objFrom1)
```